# fetch controller name from url -zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am running one project on zend framework 2.

URL is as mentioned below.

http://zf2-tutorial.localhost/album/index/page/2

from this url I would like to fetch only album in my layout.phtml.

can anyone suggest how I should do using Zend way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**To fetch the action name** `$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', 'index');`

**To fetch the controller name** `$this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', 'index');`